# Lisp dynamical scoping: A powerful short example reasoning it?

Tags: dynamic, scope, lisp

Everywhere, gurus state: "*Dynamic scoping can be so powerful over lexical scoping.*", but until now I never saw a neat example which convinced me.

Comment: Shouldn't this be in the chat section?

Comment: Look at emacs. It's also sometimes preferable to global variables.

Answer (score 3):

My favorite example is explained well in the Emacs paper: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-paper.html#SEC17

> Dynamic scope is useful. Consider the function Edit Picture, which is
>   used to change certain editing commands slightly, temporarily, so that
>   they are more convenient for editing text which is arranged into
>   two-dimensional pictures. For example, printing characters are changed
>   to replace existing text instead of shoving it over to the right. Edit
>   Picture works by binding the values of parameter variables
>   dynamically, and then calling the editor as a subroutine. The editor
>   `exit' command causes a return to the Edit Picture subroutine, which
>   returns immediately to the outer invocation of the editor. In the
>   process, the dynamic variable bindings are unmade.
>
> Dynamic binding is especially useful for elements of the command
>   dispatch table. For example, the RMAIL command for composing a reply
>   to a message temporarily defines the character Control--Meta--Y to
>   insert the text of the original message into the reply. The function
>   which implements this command is always defined, but Control--Meta--Y
>   does not call that function except while a reply is being edited. The
>   reply command does this by dynamically binding the dispatch table
>   entry for Control--Meta--Y and then calling the editor as a
>   subroutine. When the recursive invocation of the editor returns, the
>   text as edited by the user is sent as a reply.
>
> It is not necessary for dynamic scope to be the only scope rule
>   provided, just useful for it to be available.

Answer (score 3):

I got used to dynamic scope many years ago, when using the language Clipper5 (an extended implementation of the original DBIII programming language).

If used correctly dynamic scope is quite useful because it allows to pass parameters down a call chain without making intermediate functions to be necessarily aware of them.
This makes it easy to add for example new parameters only in the required place (i.e. where the parameter is originating and where the parameter is used.

Suppose you have "close-order" that calls "print-shipment-documentation" that calls "print-invoice" that calls "print-invoice-row". If you need to add a new parameter that will influence how the invoice rows are going to be printed you can just add a user option in the top level "close-order" function, set a dynamic variable with this value and only handle the value in "print-invoice-row".

The functions interface chain will remain "clean" from that parameter, listing only fundamental data to be passed.

This is similar to using a global variable, but it's "done right" because it will not remain "dirty" after the call and in most implementations supporting threads it can even be used from multiple threads without problems (each thread will have its own values).

I've found in the past the ability to use this approach for "configuration" values very helpful. You however must pay attention to avoid unwanted name clashing.

Another example of good use is `*standard-output*` in Common Lisp, i.e. a value that otherwise you need to store in a global (like the C language does) or for which the other obviously unpractical alternative would be to pass it to every function that potentially needs it (either to use it directly or to call a function that potentially needs it).

Making `*standard-output*` a dynamic variable allows a Common Lisp program to avoid citing it everywhere still maintaining the ability to redirect the standard output to something else if needed (and in a much cleaner way than in C).